# Convert roman numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a program that converts roman numbers to decimal but without using a loop now I wrote this but it gives me errors

```
def translate(mdg):
    values = {"i":1, "v":5, "x":10, "D":500, "c":100, "m":1000}
    return sum(map(lambda x: values[x], mdg))

ch = input("Entrez un nombre romain en utilisant les lettres M, D, C, X, I:")

print(translate(ch))
```

Comment: Could you please post what error you are getting and on what inputs?

Comment: You have lower case letters and you are entering upper case letters. Make sure your casing matches what you are looking up in your dictionary.

Comment: This simple approach won't work. What about numbers like `IV` or `MCM`?

Comment: Thank you guys it was upper case letter that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to use the letters in the same format of the ones that you put in the values dictionary, so all lowercase except for D.

A good solution could be to replace that uppercase "D" with a "d" and to pass ch.lower() to the translate function.

Comment: `raw_input` would be for Python 2. We would have to make sure that OP is actually using Python 2, because `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3, it is simply input. The error that is most likely coming up is not due to input either. You are on the right track with mentioning the casing, however.

Comment: name 'raw_input' is not defined That's the error I'm getting

Comment: @James you are using Python 3 most likely. Stick to `input`. `raw_input` does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you guys it was upper case letter that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with a couple appropriate modifications.

- call .lower() on the input.
- do some basic error handling that will allow only numerals in your dict as input.
- added behavior for properly evaluating numerals like IX to 9 instead of 11.

I tested this on python 3.4 and this same code also runs (with raw_input instead of input) on python 2.7. Hope that helps.

```
values = {"i":1, "v":5, "x":10, "d":500, "c":100, "m":1000}
mdg = input("Entrez un nombre romain en utilisant les lettres M, D, C, X, I:")
mdg = mdg.lower()
# small error check. make sure each mdg character is in values dict
while True:
    try:
        ## check for prefix numbers and double remove them
        ## (they were added instead of subtracted)
        ## total(im) = 999, but naiveAdd(im) = 1001
        smallerPrior = [values[mdg[x]]<values[mdg[x+1]] for x in \
                            range(len(mdg)-1)]
        break
    except KeyError:
        mdg = input("use only M, D, C, X, I:")
        mdg.lower()
        pass
firstSum = sum(map(lambda x: values[x], mdg))
overCounted = sum(map(lambda n: -2*values[mdg[n]] if smallerPrior[n] \
                else 0, range(len(smallerPrior))))

print("In Arabic numerals that is: " +str(firstSum+overCounted))
```